# Joining two tables on a third table

Tags: sql, presto

If I have two tables that do not have a direct relationship but must be joined via a third table what would be the best method?

```
artist
======
 - id
 - name

event
======
 - id
 - title
 - start_time 

artist_event
======
 - artist_id 
 - event_id
```

Would query below work to find all artists with an event in december?

```
select distinct a.name
from artist a
join artist_event ae
on a.id = ae.artist_id
join event e 
on e.id = ae.event_id
where date_trunc('month', e.start_time) = 'December'
```

Thanks

Comment: Maybe you can answer that question yourself by telling us what the output of that query is, and, if not correct, what output you actually want.  It looks largely correct to me, though I am not familiar with `DATE_TRUNC`.

Comment: I cannot run the query, thats why was asking, thanks

Comment: What is the error output/message?

Comment: I do not have access to the editor currently, it was for an exam so was asking here

Answer (score 1):

Normally, you want to include a year, when talking about a month.  So I would recommend:

```
select distinct a.name
from artist a join
     artist_event ae
     on a.id = ae.artist_id join
     event e 
     on e.id = ae.event_id
where e.start_time >= '2019-12-01' and
      e.start_time < '2020-01-01';
```

Your version won't work because `'December'` is a string (that happens to be a month name).  `date_trunc()` returns a date (which is not a string).

That said, I would recommend `exists` instead:

```
select a.name
from artist a
where exists (select 1
              from artist_event ae join
                   event e 
                   on e.id = ae.event_id
              where a.id = ae.artist_id
```

and
                        e.start_time >= '2019-12-01' and
                        e.start_time < '2020-01-01'
                 );

This eliminates the duplicate elimination in the outer query.